# Ancient Greek definition of Arete/excellence

Tags: ethics, aristotle

I've been trying to find encyclopedia entries about this but it feels like they somewhat ambiguous or don't do the word justice.

I was wondering whether Arete refers only to moral/philosophical excellence or whether it was intended to also refer to athletic endeavours or people being excellent at their day to day jobs?

Comment: From semiotics the root of the word is the same as [aristos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arete), the word which shows superlative ability and superiority, and aristos was constantly used in the plural to denote the nobility: *Educating towards arete in this sense means that the boy would be educated towards things that are actually useful in life. However, even Plato himself says that arete isn't something that can be agreed upon. He says, "Nor is there even an agreement about what constitutes arete, something that leads logically to a disagreement about the appropriate training for arete."*

Comment: See also [A Concise Inventory of Greek Etymologies](https://archive.chs.harvard.edu/CHS/article/display/6686#:~:text=Olga%20Levaniouk%202016.01.17-,%E1%BC%80%CF%81%CE%B5%CF%84%CE%AE%20(aret%E1%B8%97),-The%20term%20aret%E1%B8%97). "The noun aretḗ (ἀρετή) may be traced back to the same root as Greek ararískō (ἀραρίσκω) ‘to fit’, harmózō (ἁρμόζω) ‘to join’ and hárma (ἁρμα) ‘chariot’, or ‘the vehicle, whose parts have been fitted together’ (Prellwitz 1931), as well as Greek ἄριστος ‘the best’ (‘the most fitting one’)."

Answer (score 1):

*Arete* does indeed mean excellence in every form.  The term covers many things, which may or may not be compatible, and so it is inherently ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

*Aretê* (ἀρετή) is usually considered comparable to virtue or excellence. However, it is a vastly synthetic concept reaching beyond the particularities of the contemporary value judgements. Indeed, it may be more appropriate to keep it untranslated or note it beside its translation. The following excerpt from Stephen Miller's *Arete: Greek Sports from Ancient Sources* (3rd edition, University of California Press, 2004, p. ix), I presume, felicitously lays out its complexity:

> The Greek word arete comes down to us inextricably connected to the
> athletics of ancient Greece and laden with a plethora of meanings. A
> definition of arete would include virtue, skill, prowess, pride,
> excellence, valor, and nobility, but these words, whether taken
> individually or collectively, do not fulfill the meaning of arete.
> Arete existed, to some degree, in every ancient Greek and was, at the
> same time, a goal to be sought and reached for by every Greek. It
> cannot be translated by a direct one-to-one equivalent into the idiom
> of modern American English, and even though the context of a
> particular use of the word may refine its meaning in that context, the
> word arete still carries with it a notion of ephemeral excellence and
> of transient triumph that makes its translation an exceedingly risky
> business. In addition, the word arete has imbued ancient athletics
> with an aura of the quest of man for perfection, a quest which—at
> least in the eyes of moderns—was isolated from more practical matters
> such as politics and economics. Arete— incompletely understood—has
> thereby dimmed our picture of the realities of antiquity and has
> robbed us of many of the real lessons to be learned from ancient
> athletics.

*Aretê* appears in the fragments from such ancient philosophers as Heraclitus and Democritus, but it was Socrates by whom it came to the fore as a philosophical problematic. From then on, philosophers attempted to define the genuine or cardinal *aretê*. The themes that could be  said to run deeper throughout are the Socratic teaching of *aretê* as knowledge and the Stoic teaching as living in harmony with nature. Notice that whatever it was identified with, *aretê* was a comprehensive concept. We may observe an interesting reflection of this in language. Porphyry writes (*Porphyry: On Aristotle Categories* translated by Steven Strange, Ancient Commentators on Aristotle, Bloomsbury, 1992, p. 149):

> But in some cases the quality has a name yet we do not speak of the
> persons as named paronymously after it: for virtue is the best state
> of a person, but we do not speak of a person qualified by it as named
> paronymously after virtue. For 'virtuous' and 'envirtued' are not used
> in ordinary speech.

As the translator explicates in the footnote on the same page

> [the person who has virtue (*aretê*) is not called after *aretê*, but
> is instead called spoudaios, a word not grammatically connected with
> *aretê*. In contrast, the words *aretaios* (translated 'virtuous') and *enaretos* (translated 'envirtued': an obsolete English word meaning 'endowed with virtue'), both of which are derived paronymously from
> *aretê* in the same way as the English word 'virtuous' is derived from 'virtue', do not occur in ordinary Greek, *aretaios* is not listed in
> LSJ, and *enaretos*, 'endowed with virtue', is a jargon term of
> Hellenistic philosophy, apparently of Stoic coinage . . . hence does
> not belong to *sunêtheia* or ordinary speech].

So, there was not originally a singular feature of being "virtuous" (in the ancient sense), but there was a stage called *aretê* to be attained through acquiring "virtues" (in the contemporary sense). Thus we can say that, for ancient people, *aretê* used to encompass athletic endeavours as well as excelling at their day to day jobs.

---

Addendum

Much ink has been spilled in various scholarly disciplines over what intensionally and extensionally fall under the concept of *aretê*, going back to its Homeric usages. The significance of *aretê* can be better assessed when it is considered within the cluster of value concepts like *kleos* (κλέος, glory) and *timê* (τιμή, honour). *Aretê* is a state of one's character rather than one's property. Hence, one may cease to be in that state by an unfortunate event, or grow one's *aretê* to higher stages. It has a certain competitive side, however, one need not accomplish great deeds to have *aretê*.

No doubt the context of *aretê* we talk about at present is a value of a typical slave society. Thus, we would not expect to run across a mention of, say, a carpenter's *aretê* in an ancient text. Nonetheless, putting the matter in such a perspective makes it more a question of social sciences than of philosophy.

A nice article to enrich one's grasp of the concept is Nafsika Athanassoulis' [Virtue Ethics](https://iep.utm.edu/virtue/), while we do not limit our discussion of *aretê* to ethics.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to understand arete is to think of it as "perfection of the human form," where 'form' is used in the Platonic sense of an abstract (almost spiritual) ideal. It isn't about what one *does*; it's about what one *is* and *can be*. The term was often associated with athletics because in the ancient Greek world athletics weren't merely competitions, but were a means of demonstrating the prowess or superiority of an individual and his community. The term was also applied to the arts (drama and poetics in particular), to philosophy and intellectual matters, to politics...

Arete is a quality of a person. Doing a job well isn't arete; a person who expresses arete will naturally do a job well. But demonstrating perfection of the human form is easier in public venues like athletics, arts, philosophy, etc. than in private, more day-to-day activities. I mean, what does perfection of the human form look like in terms of (say) janitorial services? That isn't to say it doesn't exists — a janitor can certainly develop and express arete — but merely that janitorial work doesn't give one a lot of opportunity to shine (err... no pun intended).